# RegEx for extracting specific textContent in HTML tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I need to create a Python program that receives the HTML file from the standard input and outputs the names of the species displayed under Mammals to the standard output line by line using regext. I also do not need to output the item displayed as "#sequence_only".

The file used for standard input is this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

  <!-- The following setting enables collapsible lists -->
  <p>
  <a href="#human">Human</a></p>

  <p class="collapse-section">
  <a class="collapsed collapse-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
  href=#mammals>Mammals</a>
  <div class="collapse" id="mammals">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#alpaca">Alpaca</a>
  <li><a href="#armadillo">Armadillo</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Armadillo</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#baboon">Baboon</a>
  <li><a href="#bison">Bison</a>
  <li><a href="#bonobo">Bonobo</a>
  <li><a href="#brown_kiwi">Brown kiwi</a>
  <li><a href="#bushbaby">Bushbaby</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Bushbaby</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#cat">Cat</a>
  <li><a href="#chimp">Chimpanzee</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_hamster">Chinese hamster</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_pangolin">Chinese pangolin</a>
  <li><a href="#cow">Cow</a>
  <li><a href="#crab-eating_macaque">Crab-eating_macaque</a>
  <div class="gbFooterCopyright">
  &copy; 2017 The Regents of the University of California. All 
  Rights Reserved.
  <br>
  <a href="https://genome.ucsc.edu/conditions.html">Conditions of 
  Use</a>
  </div>
```

My logics is as following. I want to parse the value of href. If the line  starts with < li > and the value of href starts from "#" --> it is a species name and I need to extract name between ">< characters. If the value of href starts from "https", I want to re.sub it with some other character and do not input in the final output.

I tried to create the regex for extracting mammals name.

```
#!usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import re

html = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in html:

    mammal_name = re.search(r'\"\>(.*?)\<', line)

if mammal_name:

    print(mammal_name.group())
```

I wanted output like:

```
Alpaca
Armadillo
Baboon
```

I got output like:

```
">Human<
">Alpaca<
">Armadillo<
">Armadillo<
">Baboon<
```

I do not want Human to be in output as the line it is at does not start with < li >. Moreover, I do not want the repetitions in my output but for that I need to access value of href but I am struggling with this part.

**UPDATE**: My grader shows me message like this: "If you enclose species name in tags, it will be displayed in italics in many browsers, so the staff who wanted to display scientific names in italics probably used tags. In any case, it is inappropriate as a species name, so please remove it". I guess it is about >(species name)<, so I need to replace >< between which species name is with some other character, probably [] and do parsing for my regex after that??

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I have already read this but I need to use regex for my homework.

Comment: Why is your class teaching you to parse HTML with regex??

Comment: @DariObukhova, Check my answer, it should be helpful for you.

Comment: @Olvin Rogth, thanks a lot! Also, as far as I got from my grader before extracting the species names, I need to change >< that they are between to something else as these characters might create the output in italics in some browsers. Could you help me with this as well?

Comment: @DariObukhova, but there's no "><" in output of my example, what are you actually speaking about?

Answer (score 2):

Here, we just want to add two left (`<li><a.+?>`) and right boundaries (`<\/.+>`), then swipe our desired outputs and save it in `$1` capturing group `()`:

```
<li><a.+?>(.+)?<\/.+>
```

#### Test

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = """
!-- The following setting enables collapsible lists -->
  <p>
  <a href="#human">Human</a></p>

  <p class="collapse-section">
  <a class="collapsed collapse-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
  href=#mammals>Mammals</a>
  <div class="collapse" id="mammals">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#alpaca">Alpaca</a>
  <li><a href="#armadillo">Armadillo</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Armadillo</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#baboon">Baboon</a>
  <li><a href="#bison">Bison</a>
  <li><a href="#bonobo">Bonobo</a>
  <li><a href="#brown_kiwi">Brown kiwi</a>
  <li><a href="#bushbaby">Bushbaby</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Bushbaby</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#cat">Cat</a>
  <li><a href="#chimp">Chimpanzee</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_hamster">Chinese hamster</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_pangolin">Chinese pangolin</a>
  <li><a href="#cow">Cow</a>
  <li><a href="#crab-eating_macaque">Crab-eating_macaque</a>
  <div class="gbFooterCopyright">
  &copy; 2017 The Regents of the University of California. All 
  Rights Reserved.
  <br>
  <a href="https://genome.ucsc.edu/conditions.html">Conditions of 
  Use</a>
  </div>
"""
expression = r'<li><a.+?>(.+)?<\/.+>'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! "Alpaca" is a match
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rEcZXz/1).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

---

Edit:

To exclude, `sequence_only`, we can modify our expression to:

```
<li.+?#[^s].+?>(.+)?<\/.+>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6vi3wZ/1)

#### Python

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

test_str = '''

<!DOCTYPE html>

  <!-- The following setting enables collapsible lists -->
  <p>
  <a href="#human">Human</a></p>

  <p class="collapse-section">
  <a class="collapsed collapse-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
  href=#mammals>Mammals</a>
  <div class="collapse" id="mammals">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#alpaca">Alpaca</a>
  <li><a href="#armadillo">Armadillo</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Armadillo</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#baboon">Baboon</a>
  <li><a href="#bison">Bison</a>
  <li><a href="#bonobo">Bonobo</a>
  <li><a href="#brown_kiwi">Brown kiwi</a>
  <li><a href="#bushbaby">Bushbaby</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Bushbaby</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#cat">Cat</a>
  <li><a href="#chimp">Chimpanzee</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_hamster">Chinese hamster</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_pangolin">Chinese pangolin</a>
  <li><a href="#cow">Cow</a>
  <li><a href="#crab-eating_macaque">Crab-eating_macaque</a>
  <div class="gbFooterCopyright">
  &copy; 2017 The Regents of the University of California. All 
  Rights Reserved.
  <br>
  <a href="https://genome.ucsc.edu/conditions.html">Conditions of 
  Use</a>
  </div>

'''
regex = r"<li.+?#[^s].+?>(.+)?<\/.+>"
find_matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
for matches in find_matches:
    print(matches)
```

#### Output

```
Alpaca
Armadillo
Baboon
Bison
Bonobo
Brown kiwi
Bushbaby
Cat
Chimpanzee
Chinese hamster
Chinese pangolin
Cow
Crab-eating_macaque
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation. It worked. The only problem left is that I do not need output the names where < li ><a href="#sequence_only". Can I solve it somehow using regex, probably re.sub?

Comment: Thanks so much. I got the architecture of this regex. Sorry to be so bothersome, but is it also a way to replace >< between which name of species are because the grader shows me it might be the reason the species name is output in some browsers in italic?

Comment: I have updated my question. The grader output is weird indeed but my guess is that I need to do that to escape output in italics in some browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Use BeautifulSoup, it is a powerful package for html parsing:

```
import re
import codecs

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from lxml import html

# Change with your input file 
input_html = "D:\/input.html"

with codecs.open(input_html, 'r', "utf-8") as f :
    page = f.read()
f.close()
#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page, "html.parser")

#extract document seperator:
divTag = page_soup.find_all("div", {"id": "mammals"})

for tag in divTag:
    mammals = tag.find_all("a", href = re.compile(r'#(?!sequence_only$)'))
    for tag in mammals:
        print(tag.text)
```

Output :

```
Alpaca
Armadillo
Baboon
Bison
Bonobo
Brown kiwi
Bushbaby
Cat
Chimpanzee
Chinese hamster
Chinese pangolin
Cow
Crab-eating_macaque
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem now is how to NOT output the names where href value = #sequence_only. For example, Armadillo and Bushbaby need to be output only once..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that criteria, I just edited it ! happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

use `re.findall` to get all tags text text
like this

```
pattern = r'<li><a.*>(.*)</a>'
find = re.findall(pattern, string)
if find:
    print(find)
```

out put

```
['Alpaca', 'Armadillo', 'Armadillo', 'Baboon', 'Bison', 'Bonobo', 'Brown kiwi', 
'Bushbaby', 'Bushbaby', 'Cat', 'Chimpanzee', 'Chinese hamster', 'Chinese pangolin', 
'Cow', 'Crab-eating_macaque']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should add some details to your regex to parse correct strings. [Regex test website](https://regex101.com/r/bhyl0X/4).

**Input:**

```
string = '''   <!DOCTYPE html>

  <!-- The following setting enables collapsible lists -->
  <p>
  <a href="#human">Human</a></p>

  <p class="collapse-section">
  <a class="collapsed collapse-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
  href=#mammals>Mammals</a>
  <div class="collapse" id="mammals">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#alpaca">Alpaca</a>
  <li><a href="#armadillo">Armadillo</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Armadillo</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#baboon">Baboon</a>
  <li><a href="#bison">Bison</a>
  <li><a href="#bonobo">Bonobo</a>
  <li><a href="#brown_kiwi">Brown kiwi</a>
  <li><a href="#bushbaby">Bushbaby</a>
  <li><a href="#sequence_only">Bushbaby</a> (sequence only)
  <li><a href="#cat">Cat</a>
  <li><a href="#chimp">Chimpanzee</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_hamster">Chinese hamster</a>
  <li><a href="#chinese_pangolin">Chinese pangolin</a>
  <li><a href="#cow">Cow</a>
  <li><a href="#crab-eating_macaque">Crab-eating_macaque</a>
  <div class="gbFooterCopyright">
  &copy; 2017 The Regents of the University of California. All 
  Rights Reserved.
  <br>
  <a href="https://genome.ucsc.edu/conditions.html">Conditions of 
  Use</a>
  </div>'''
```

If you want to process all text in one expression you should use [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). **Code:**

```
results = re.findall("<li><a href=\"(?:(?!#sequence_only).)*\">(.*)</a>", string)
for s in results:
    print(s)
```

If you want to check it line by line, you can use [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). **Code:**

```
strings = string.splitlines()
for s in strings:
    substring = re.search("<li><a href=\"(?:(?!#sequence_only).)*\">(.*)</a>", s)
    if substring:
        print(substring.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
Alpaca
Armadillo
Baboon
Bison
Bonobo
Brown kiwi
Bushbaby
Cat
Chimpanzee
Chinese hamster
Chinese pangolin
Cow
Crab-eating_macaque
```